# beautifulsoup could not find class

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I tried to use bs4 to get the table from one NBA stat site.

The website seems did not use the JavaScript.

The `soup.prettify` print result looks normal, but I could not use `soup.find_all` to get the table I want. Here's the code I'm using:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://stats.nba.com/team/#!/1610612738/stats/'
page = requests.get(url)
html = page.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser') 

tables = soup.find_all('table')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The website loads data with [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started), and this data will not be available to you simply by getting page contents with BeautifulSoup. However, you probably don't need BeautifulSoup at all.

If you're using Chrome, visit the website and go to your browser's dev tools, click on the network tab, click the XHR filter, then reload the page. You'll see 
a list of requests that were made:

[image]

Click on those and see which ones you're interested in. Once you find the one you like, copy the url, and get the data with the requests library (you already included this in your code):

```
r = requests.get('http://stats.nba.com/stats/commonallplayers?IsOnlyCurrentSeason=0&LeagueID=00&Season=2016-17')
data = r.json()
```